# Delete part of variable if this part begin with slash

Tags: php, string, variables

```
    $string ="string
    string
    //deleteme
    string
    //deleteme
    // deleteme
    string";
```

How to remove all the lines that begin with a double slash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the entire line:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\/\/\S*[^\n]+\n?/','',$string);
```

Comment: After using it i met a problem. How to exclude urls? So, delete part of line which begins with // but don't delete if it begins with ://

Answer (score 1):

i guess you should use preg_replace to replace the words/lines with an empty string. something like:

```
$regex = '/ \/\/ [^\n]* \n /';
preg_replace($regex, '', $string);
```

Comment: ah, i see that there was someone before me.